# How to create .cab archive in php

Tags: php, compressed-files, compressed-class

i create 10 files xml with onclick button on my site and i want put all 10 files in archive .cab extension in php.

I try to use a class MakeCAB found in https://www.phpclasses.org/package/4056-PHP-Create-CAB-archives-from-lists-of-files.html but this class is obsolete.
i try to update (i change name of __construct) it, but still error and output fil .cab is corrupt.
how can i do that? please.

I still have the 2 errors Undefined index and filettr but I don't know how to define them, I don't know if this is the cause of the problem, which is that the generation of the .cab works but there may be a size limit weight or other because it always truncates me one file.

```
function WriteFiles($res)
{ foreach ( $this->cabfiles as $file ) 
{ $this->WriteDword( $res, $file['ucomp'] ); 
$this->WriteDword( $res, $file['offset'] ); 
$this->WriteWord( $res, $file['index'] ); (line 314 ici) 
$this->WriteWord( $res, $file['date'] ); 
$this->WriteWord( $res, $file['time'] ); 
$this->WriteWord( $res, $file['fileattr'] ); (line 317 ici) 
$this->WriteByteBuffer( $res, $file['name'] ); 
} }
```

Some variables and index defined but maybe not all.

```
var $cabfile;
 /** * Array of files to be added to archive
 * * @var array * 
@access protected  */ 
var $cabfiles = array(); 

/** * Array of data for CAB folder
 * * @var array * 
@access protected*/ 
var $cabfolder = array(
'offset' => 44, ## offset of data            
'numblocks' => 0,  ## number of blocks           
'typecmp' => 1, ## 0 = no compression; 1 = MSZIP; LZX                                
'fileoffset' => 0  );

/** * Array of data for CAB Header * * 
@var array * 
@access protected */ 
var $cabheader = array(
'sig' => "MSCF",    ## signature             
'res1' => 0, ## reserved space          
'size' => 44, ## total size of cab file             
'res2' => 0,            
'offset' => 44,  ## offset of first data block      
'res3' => 0,            
'vmaj' => 1,    ## cab file format major version number 1            
'vmin' => 3,    ## cab file format minor version number 3            
'numfolders' => 1, ## must have at least one folder 

NewCABFolder()           
'numfiles' => 0, ## number of files in cab file              
'flags' => 0, ## not supported          
'setid' => 1234, ## set ID (not supported)           
'cabid' => 0, ##cab id not supported            
);
 /**
```

I call class like code bellow

```
//Send the MSCAB MIME type
 header("Content-Type:application/vnd.ms-cab- 
 compressed"); 

//Make it an attachment 
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; 
 filename="WinMSS.cab"'); 

//include the class file 
include'lib/makecab/MakeCAB.class.php'; 

//create object 
$cab = new MakeCAB("WinMSS.cab"); 

//add a local file system file 
$cab->addfile("WinMSS/STAGE.xml"); 
$cab->addfile("WinMSS/THEMATCH.xml"); 
$cab->addfile("WinMSS/CLASSIFY.xml"); 
$cab->addfile("WinMSS/CLUB.xml"); 
$cab->addfile("WinMSS/ENROLLED.xml"); 
$cab->addfile("WinMSS/MEMBER.xml"); 
$cab->addfile("WinMSS/SCORE.xml"); 
$cab->addfile("WinMSS/SQUAD.xml"); 
$cab->addfile("WinMSS/TAG.xml"); 
$cab->addfile("WinMSS/TEAM.xml");

//Make the file 
$cab->WriteCAB(); 

//output the file 
readfile("WinMSS.cab");

//delete the file 
unlink("WinMSS.cab"); } ?>
```

I am open to other technical solutions:

use an online compression tool but it takes time

use a language other than php compatible with an html css website etc ...

don't hesitate to give me ideas please
Thank you.

Comment: If you have already written some code, you could share it such that others could check it for errors

Comment: Please edit your question to contain all information. Don't put relevant information in the comment section. Additionally, share your debugging attempts